# error trying to create callback

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, bluetooth-lowenergy

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <wrl\wrappers\corewrappers.h>
#include <wrl\client.h>
#include <wrl\event.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <../winrt/windows.devices.bluetooth.h>
#include <../winrt/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.h>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace Microsoft::WRL;
using namespace Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers;
using namespace ABI::Windows::Foundation;
using namespace ABI::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::Advertisement;
using namespace ABI::Windows::UI::Input;


// Prints an error string for the provided source code line and HRESULT
// value and returns the HRESULT value as an int.
int PrintError(unsigned int line, HRESULT hr)
{
    wprintf_s(L"ERROR: Line:%d HRESULT: 0x%X\n", line, hr);
    return hr;
}
struct Test {
    Test() {}
    Test(int i) {}

    HRESULT OnConnectionReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher* watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs* args) {
        MessageBox(0, L"connected", L"MessageBox caption", MB_OK);
        return S_OK;
    }
};

EventRegistrationToken *watcherToken;


int main()
{
    watcherToken = new EventRegistrationToken();

    // Initialize the Windows Runtime.
    RoInitializeWrapper initialize(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(initialize))
    {
        return PrintError(__LINE__, initialize);
    }

    // Get the activation factory for the IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherFactory interface.
    ComPtr<IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherFactory> bleAdvWatcherFactory;
    HRESULT hr = GetActivationFactory(HStringReference(RuntimeClass_Windows_Devices_Bluetooth_Advertisement_BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher).Get(), &bleAdvWatcherFactory);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return PrintError(__LINE__, hr);
    }


    ComPtr<IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher> bleWatcher;
    ComPtr<IBluetoothLEAdvertisementFilter> bleFilter;


    Wrappers::HStringReference class_id_filter2(RuntimeClass_Windows_Devices_Bluetooth_Advertisement_BluetoothLEAdvertisementFilter);
    hr = RoActivateInstance(class_id_filter2.Get(), reinterpret_cast<IInspectable**>(bleFilter.GetAddressOf()));
    hr = bleAdvWatcherFactory->Create(bleFilter.Get(), &bleWatcher);



    if (bleWatcher == NULL)
    {
        cout << "bleWatcher is NULL, err is " << hex << hr;
    }
    else
    {
        bleWatcher->Start();
        Test test;
        //Problem is here
        ComPtr<ITypedEventHandler<BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher*, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs*>> handler;
        handler = Callback<ITypedEventHandler<BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher*, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs*> > 
            (std::bind(
                &Test::OnConnectionReceived,
                &test,
                placeholders::_1,
                placeholders::_2
            ));

    hr = bleWatcher->add_Received(handler.Get(), watcherToken);
        while (1) {

            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to handle the event generated by bleWatcher when a connection is received, when I try to create my callback I receive the error, 
Error   C2664   'HRESULT Microsoft::WRL::DelegateTraits::CheckReturn(HRESULT)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::_Unforced' to 'HRESULT'

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/e321cb3c-462a-4b16-b7e4-febdb3d0c7d6/windows-10-pairing-a-ble-device-from-code?forum=wdk&prof=required

User steno916 seems to have figured out how to handle this, but I cannot understand what he has done from his provided code.

Comment: You just need to define OnConnectionReceived's argument to be pointers to interfaces (IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher* and IBluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs*), not classes.

Comment: You are my hero sir, I have no idea how I couldn't figure this out, but I thank you greatly change this from comment to answer and your bounty shall be awarded.

Comment: Well, too late! Hans sort of destroyed the bounty with the answer he's made under community wiki...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> note: while compiling class template member function 'HRESULT Microsoft::WRL::Details::InvokeHelper::Invoke(ABI::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::Advertisement::IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher *,ABI::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::Advertisement::IBluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs *)'

Template compile error messages can be, erm, painful.  This one is certainly a mother, the problem has nothing to do with HRESULT.  Very important to look in the Output window to read the full error message.  This is the part of the message that provides the essential hint to help you diagnose what went wrong.

Still, even then you can look at it for an hour or a day and still not see it. Sometimes it is useful to edit it down, replacing very long names by short ones to cut down on the noise level.  Might reveal the essential detail, note how it passes *interface pointers* to Invoke().  So the callback must likewise use interface pointers in its signature.  Add two I's:

```
HRESULT OnConnectionReceived(IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher* watcher,
                             IBluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs* args) {
    // etc...
}
```